# Re-map evil-commentary key in dired mode

Tags: evil, dired

I am trying to re-map a key in `evil-mode`/`evil-commentary-mode` when in `dired-mode`. I tried to add a hook to `dired-mode` to disable the minor commentary mode, but it disables it for other major modes as well. I've tried the following as well but it doesn't work (I've also tried it with `evil-normal-state-map`):

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key evil-commentary-mode-map (kbd "g") 'revert-buffer)))
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have evil-commentary enabled in Dired? I mean, yes, you can edit things in dired, but this seems to be an odd workaround...

Comment: It's enabled by globally. I want to disable it for some non-editable modes. I guess I could do the other way around and try to enable it for editable modes only. When I disable it with a hook to `dired-mode` it gets disabled globally.

Comment: I see. Well, there should be a way...

Comment: I guess, it's because `g` is a prefix for other `evil-mode` commands, and I think I was silly trying to re-map it. I use space as my leading key in normal state so just binded `revert-buffer` to `<SPC> r` in `dired-mode`.

Comment: No, it's because evil-commentary-mode defines these keys for normal state and dired is in normal state. I see absolutely no reason for it to be. Other than, like, allow people to just navigate it without actually doing any useful action inside.

Comment: `(evil-define-key 'normal dired-mode-map (kbd "f") 'evil-emacs-state)` works but `(evil-define-key 'normal dired-mode-map (kbd "g") 'revert-buffer)` doesn't. I don't understand why. I got back to normal state before pressing `g` obviously: `(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
   (lambda() (local-set-key (kbd "f") 'evil-normal-state)))` Just as a side note, I try to use `f` do dip in and out of `emacs-state` in few non-editable major modes like `org-agenda-mode`.

Comment: The reason I thought it didn't work was because `g` is a leading key for `evil-commentary-mode`. Anyway, I was just wondering, I did work around that issue.